# Keep dialog open after non-ajax request

Tags: jsf, navigation, primefaces

I've got a few JSF pages having a PrimeFaces dialog to create a `Person`. Because this dialog contains a file upload I don't want to use AJAX. The dialog is to be closed when the `Person` is created. If the `Person` isn't created (validation fails or whatever) the dialog should be shown.

I've seen people do this using `visible="#{not empty facesContext.messages}"`, I however cannot use this because the method that is called returns a `FacesMessage` in any case.

The idea I now have is to generate a view parameter (showDialog for example) and use `visible="#{param.showDialog}"`.

I've tried using navigation cases but since the method is called from several pages I cannot make a generic navigation case that only adds a view parameter. This would be the idea:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{personBean.create}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>#{from-view-id}</to-view-id>
        <redirect>
            <view-param>
                <name>showDialog</name>
                <value>#{form-outcome}</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Another problem with using navigation cases is that the dialog is a composite tag and the action is supplied using an attribute. When I do use a navigation case like the one above I get a message saying `Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/test.xhtml' for action '#{cc.attrs.saveAction}' with outcome 'true'`.

I think the best/easiest solution is to add the view parameter in the method. However the requestmap is immutable and returning a String containing `?showDialog=true` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works without the view parameter idea.

To submit the form I use a `p:commandButton` this button uses AJAX. This button only sets the fields, validates the fields and updates the container of the input fields. Luckily PrimeFaces returns a JavaScript value (`args.validationFailed`) indicating the validation failed or not.

When I click the save button the fields get validated through AJAX and thus keeping the dialog open. When the validation passes I click the non-AJAX link using JavaScript.

JSF:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" update="containerOfValues"
    oncomplete="afterValidation(xhr, status, args)" />
<p:commandLink ajax="false" action="#{cc.attrs.saveAction}"
    style="display:none" binding="#{saveLink}" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function afterValidation(xhr, status, args)
{
    if (!args.validationFailed)
    {
        $("[id='#{saveLink.clientId}']").click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't handle it with navigation rules, but rather make it similar to the [Login Example of the Primefaces Showcases](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf) . As you can see there the dialog remains open when validation fails and closes if the submit action succeeded.

Comment: The main difference between the example and my case is that I'm not using AJAX. Else I wouldn't have to post a question here ;-)